# EF Core tries to add new record instead of update 1:many relation

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure why while trying to create an entity which is 1:many
EF tries to add new entry in Asp Net Users instead of update 1:many

I have one `user` which has many `items`

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (cdbb1f2f-ddcf-40c0-97ec-f50f8049d87a).

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}
```

---

```
public class Item
{
    private Item()
    {

    }

    public Item(string title, User owner, File file)
    {
        Title = title;
        Owner = owner;
        File = file;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public File File { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

---

And here's where's the problem:

```
var fileResult = await _file.SaveFile(input.File);
var item = new Item(input.Title, user, fileResult.File);

user.Items.Add(item);
await _context.Items.AddAsync(item);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

User is loaded with:

```
public User GetUser()
{
    return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == _http.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
}
```

I tried that:

When I change

```
public Item(string title, User owner, File file)
{
    Title = title;
    Owner = owner;
    File = file;
}
```

to just:

```
public Item(string title, File file)
{
    Title = title;
    File = file;
}
```

and let it be handled by:

```
user.Items.Add(item);
```

then OwnerId in DB is null

Using:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Items)
        .WithOne(x => x.Owner);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOne(x => x.Owner);
}
```

is not helping either

Comment: You need to add `public Guid OwnerId {get; set;}` to your item's class and fill it with the user's ID. That way EF will understand implicitly that there is a 1:many relationship between Item and User.

Comment: @Dennis1679 `user.Items.Add(item);item.Owner = user;item.OwnerId = user.Id;` with `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Items).WithOne(x => x.Owner).HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);` `and once again `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers`

Comment: In respect to my previous comment; I'm not 100% sure but I think that - if you want to build the relationship without specifying it in the fluent API - you need to rename Owner to User and UserId respectively.

Comment: Looks like the object in `user` variable is not tracked by the context (otherwise `user.Items.Add(item);` would be sufficient, you won't need `await _context.Items.AddAsync(item);` and won't get the exception). Can you verify that - see if `Debug.Assert(_context.Users.Local.Contains(user));` fails?

Comment: @IvanStoev You gave me a huge hint and now I realized what causing this problem. I changed `(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]), ServiceLifetime.Transient);` to `(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);` (DI Lifetime) and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was casued by `ServiceLifetime` of DbContext

Because User was loaded in `Controller` and then thrawn into `Service` that was responsible for business logic

I changed

`(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]), ServiceLifetime.Transient);`

to

`(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);`

and it works fine.